# Pandas: check if column value is unique

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like:

```
         value
0          1
1          2
2          2
3          3
4          4
5          4
```

I need to check if each value is unique or not, and mark that boolean value to new column. Expected result would be:

```
         value        unique
0          1           True
1          2           False
2          2           False
3          3           True
4          4           False
5          4           False
```

I have tried:

```
df['unique'] = ""
df.loc[df["value"].is_unique, 'unique'] = True
```

But this throws exception:

```
cannot use a single bool to index into setitem
```

Any advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) witn invert mask by `~`:

```
df['unique'] = ~df['value'].duplicated(keep=False)
print (df)
   value  unique
0      1    True
1      2   False
2      2   False
3      3    True
4      4   False
5      4   False
```

Or:

```
df['unique'] = np.where(df['value'].duplicated(keep=False), False, True)
```

Comment: Works perfectly like your answers always... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```py
df['unique'] = df.merge(df.value_counts().to_frame(), on='value')[0]==1
```